# Using zeromq in a distributed load pipeline, can I get the address of the last server a message was sent to

Tags: python, zeromq

If I set up a pipeline which distributes load across a cluster, I would like to log where the messages get sent.  This is what I have in mind (python):

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.DOWNSTREAM)
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000")
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:6000")

msg = "Hello World\0"
connection_string = socket.send(msg)
# should print "Sent message to tcp://127.0.0.1:5000"
print "Sent message to", connection_string
```

But I cant find anything that talks about this.  Any help at all is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It think you'll want to use the X(REP|REQ) sockets somewhere in the topology for this. You might want to checkout the monitered queue device:
http://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/zmq/devices.pyx

And for general info have a look at the diagram and explanations of the patterns here too:
http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/nightly/html/development/parallel_connections.html

Also note that the DOWNSTREAM socket type is now called PUSH (and the corresponding UPSTREAM has changed to PULL).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could include the address of the recipient within the reply and log it then?

Comment: Only for some message patterns (e.g. REQ/REP). For PUSH/PULL there is no reply.

Answer (score 0):

My 0.02 cents...

Well i believe since ZMQ routes in fair queue manner, that would be round robin. Hence messages would be sent to recepients in order. However, writing code under that assumption would not be the right thing since the underlying routing logic might change in future versions.

For PUSH/PULL, i am not sure, however for REQ/REP, i guess the REP side can send the reply back in an envolope with the first field as its address. That way the REQ can read twice on the socket and get the responder address as well as the data.